# Why loading nextjs csv file does not work?

Tags: csv, next.js, multer

I have a problem loading a csv file. The images are loaded OK...
The fact is that the csv file does not have time to load and be renamed in the downloads folder if I execute return.json, but if it is commented out as in the code below - everything is OK, there are no problems with images at all, that is, it has to do with the file size, the csv is very small , the image is much more natural. What is the problem, why is this happening and how to fix it?

client:

```
...
const formData = new FormData();
formData.append('file', acceptedFiles[0]);
fetch('/upload/file', {
    method: 'POST',
    body: formData,
})
.then((response) => response.json())
```

server:

```
const upload = multer({dest: 'uploads/', limits: {fieldSize: MAX_RECORD_SIZE}});
router.post('/file', upload.single('file'), (req: Request, res: Response) => {
    const file = req.file.filename + path.extname(req.file.originalname);
    const folder = './uploads' ;
    fs.renameSync('./uploads/' + req.file.filename, folder + '/' + file)
    // return res.json({
    //     success: true,
    //     file,
    //     message: 'uploaded successfully!',
    // });
});
```